# Google Rich Snippets indexing fall

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, rich-snippets

To 12th November 2013 there were about 3000 pages with structured data indexed for our site according to Google Webmaster Tools. There were stars and all related information in search results.

But after the 12th, a sharp drop began in indexing and at this moment we are seeing that only 54 pages will display stars in search results and this is true.

We can't understand why it happened.

Here are some facts that maybe useful:

1. On November 1st we have moved our site from http to https and added 301 redirects from http to https pages.
2. On November 25th we have broken some structured data markup but fixed it on December 2nd.
3. We have made a request to Google Support about Rich Snippets and they said that markup is valid:

   > Thank you for your interest in rich snippets for your site.
   >
   > We have now reviewed your site and found that your usage of structured
   >   data markup meets our guidelines and is eligible to have rich snippets
   >   shown in our search results.
   >
   > Regards, The Google Team for Rich Snippets
4. There are still some old links with http schema exist in Google Search results with stars (e.g. https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=East+Meets+West+Yoga+-+Williamsville).
5. We tried to change pages' meta descriptions and Google re-indexed them. But structured data still don't appear.

**Here is Structured Data index status chart:**

[image: Google Structured Data chart]

**Here are some links:**

https://www.wellnessliving.com/ms/bikeorbar/review/ 
https://www.wellnessliving.com/ms/body__brain_yoga_clark/review/ 
https://www.wellnessliving.com/ms/dahn_yoga_center_libertyville/review/ 
https://www.wellnessliving.com/ms/sacred_sounds_yoga/review/

Two weeks passed but nothing changed. Please, help :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a [relevant article](http://www.searchenginejournal.com/rich-snippets-the-phenomenon/75095/):

> ...don’t be discouraged if your Rich Snippets do a disappearing act. Google is constantly testing and modifying its algorithms. Here’s the best way to react:
>
> - Leave your markup code as is for at least 8 weeks and just monitor the ups and downs of your Rich Snippets. They mean Google is continually analyzing your site.
> - As long as your Rich Snippets don’t disappear for more than two weeks in a row, there likely isn’t a problem with your markup.
> - If you panic and mess with your markup during this phase, you risk sending Google mixed signals about the authenticity of your web pages.
> - If you’re genuinely worried about the correctness of your markup implementation, have someone in the know audit your site for errors before you make any changes.
> - If after 8 weeks or so, you don’t have any Rich Snippets, or if you had some early on but they’ve been gone for weeks, something’s not right.
> - If you never received any Rich Snippets, there could be errors in your Schema.org implementation.
> - If you got some Rich Snippets initially but they disappeared permanently – without your making any modifications to your Schema.org markup – there are a couple of possibilities: If the markup was manual, not automated, there could be what are called coupling code errors; you’ll need a Schema.org pro to sort this out. Alternatively, Google may have tagged your site for suspected nefarious black-hat SEO practices, and the punishment is holding back on Rich Snippets.

Comment: The same for Bing and Yahoo. We have not checked them before, but they also do not have stars in search results.